# Inserir dados na base de dados conforme número de checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Eu tenho um `form` onde tenho campos com chekboxes e quero saber se é possível fazer tantos `inserts` como campos selecionados. Ou seja se o utilizador selecionar 4 `checkboxes` faço 4 `inserts`, é possível? Se sim, como posso fazer?

Código dos checkboxes:

```
    <?
                $result = $connection -> query("select * from produtos");
                while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $titulo = $row['titulo'];
                    $numeroproduto = $row['id'];
                ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="relacionados[]" id="relacionados" value="<?=$id?>" onClick="verificar()"><?=$titulo?><br>
                <?
                }
                ?>
```

E este aqui é o código onde faço os inserts já com a ajuda que me deram, mas ele não insere. Alguém me consegue ajudar?

```
$result = $connection -> query("insert into centrobemestar values(NULL,'$titulo','$texto','$produtos_relacionados', '$pastafinal', '$linguagem')"); $result -> free();

        $id_centrobemestar = $result -> insert_id;      

        $total_opcoes = count($_POST['relacionados']);
        $values =  substr(str_repeat("(NULL,'$id_centrobemestar','?'),", $total_opcoes),0 , -1);
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO tags VALUES '. $values ;

        foreach($_POST['relacionados'] as $item){
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $item);
        }

        $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo $stmt->error;
        }
```

Modifiquei o código e o erro deixou de aparecer, agora apenas me aparece um warning.
Com o seguinte código ele já insere na base de dados, mas tudo a zero.

Warning:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /home/devbor/public_html/hausmann/admin/pesquisacentrobemestar.php on line 201

Código:

```
        $result = $connection -> query("insert into centrobemestar values(NULL,'$titulo','$texto','$produtos_relacionados', '$pastafinal', '$linguagem')"); $result -> free;

        $id_centrobemestar = $result -> insert_id;      

        $total_opcoes = count($_POST['relacionados']);
        $values =  substr(str_repeat("(NULL,'$id_centrobemestar','?'),", $total_opcoes),0 , -1);
        $sql = $connection -> prepare('INSERT INTO tags VALUES '. $values ) ;

        foreach($_POST['relacionados'] as $item){
            $sql->bind_param('i', $item);
        }

        $sql -> execute();
```

Comment: Sim é possível, você pode fazer um unico insert passado vários `VALUES` separado por virgula. Coloque o código dos seus checkbox.

Comment: Já inseri o código pedido

Comment: O problema parece estar no bind_param, aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não, penso que não apareça pq antes faço um upload de uma imagem, que redirecciona automaticamente e não permite ver os erros.

Comment: Comente as linhas do redirecionamento.

Comment: Vou testar a ver o que aparece e já digo algo

Comment: rray tinhas razão, está a dar-me erro no bind_param. Mais especificamente o erro é este:   
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/devbor/public_html/hausmann/admin/pesquisacentrobemestar.php on line 201

Comment: Faltou uma linha, a do `prepare()` atualizei a minha resposta.

Comment: o certo nao seria bindParam? e modiciar `?` por `:item` e `bindParam(':item',$item)`;

Comment: Eu acho que está a dar erro porque ele não está a receber o `$connection`

Comment: Ok, modifiquei o código, ele já insere mas dá me um warning.
`Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home/devbor/public_html/hausmann/admin/pesquisacentrobemestar.php on line 201` ele já insere na base de dados, mas tudo a zero

Answer (score 3):

Faça um unico insert passando vários `values`, lembre de verificar se exite algum item marcado no checkcbox. Depois passe o número correto de campos por clásula `VALUES` para fazer o o bind corretamente, [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) remove a última virgula da string.

```
<?php
$total_opcoes = count($_POST['relacionados']);
$values =  substr(str_repeat('(?),', $total_opcoes),0 , -1);
$sql = 'INSERT  produtos INTO (relacionado) VALUES '. $values ;

$stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

foreach($_POST['relacionados'] as $item){
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $item);
}


if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo $stmt->error;
}
```

A sql será dessa mais ou menos dessa forma, usei 5 itens como exemplo e apenas um campo.

```
INSERT produto INTO (relacionado) VALUES (?),(?),(?),(?),(?)
```

**Relacionada:**

[Mysqli fazer bind com um array de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101977/91)

Comment: E eu posso, com esse código, inserir os dados que bem no checkboxe?

Answer (score 0):

Já está resolvido. Estava a ter problema com o `NULL` porque não sei passar o `NULL` na função `bind_param`, então fiz assim:

```
$result = $connection -> query("insert into centrobemestar values(NULL,'$titulo','$texto','$produtos_relacionados', '$pastafinal', '$linguagem')"); 

        $id_centrobemestar = $connection -> insert_id;
        $result -> free;
        if( count($_POST['relacionados']) ){
            foreach($_POST['relacionados'] as $item)
                $values .= "(NULL,'".(int)$id_centrobemestar."','".(int)$item."'),";
            $result = $connection -> query('INSERT INTO tags VALUES '.substr($values,0,-1) ); $result -> free;
        }
```