# Mysqli fazer bind com um array de valores

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, bind

Eu tenho um código em PDO e preciso de converter esse código para mysqli, neste momento tenho algo do gênero:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from tabela where nome = ? AND idade = ? AND outro = ?";

$stmt = $core->conn->prepare($sql);

$bindArray = array( $_POST['nome'], $_POST['idade'], $_POST['outro'] );

$stmt->execute($bindArray);
```

O problema está no $bindArray, no PDO na função execute passo a variável $bindArray e ele automaticamente faz bind ao array, no mysqli não estou a conseguir.

O que poderá estar errado ou não é possível fazer o mesmo com mysqli?

Comment: [Como passo parâmetros dinamicos numa preparedStatment?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101087/91) e 
[Select no MySQL com um array](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30181/91)

Comment: Eu estou ciente dessas soluções, mas eu quero saber se é possível fazer o bind como em PDO, sem estar a recorrer ao uso call_user_func_array e afins.

Comment: Hoje não possível, o MySQLi peca em algumas coisas e também é bom em outras.

Comment: Impossível não sei, mas de momento o que digo é que teria de se elaborar uma expressão bem complexa para fazer esse serviço. Talvez não muito complexa, mas também não seria simples. Caso eu tenha mais tempo disponível, veremos.

Comment: @Edilson, Como a API não disponibiliza nada que faça isso, gostaria muito de ver a sua solução sem usar `call_user_func_array()`. Existem razões tecnicas para `execute()` não receber um array e `bind_param()` só aceitar referências.

Comment: Por acaso até existe, mas eu não disse que a solução não seria com base na função `call_user_func_array`. Talvez tenha lido mal o teu comentário, contudo continua a existir uma forma alternativa, porém trabalhosa e nada recomendável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atualmente não é possível passar um array para [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) do MySQLi da mesma forma que trabalha o [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) do PDO, passar valores também diretamente via [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) não é possível, curiosamente retornos de função geram um warning e funcionam.

A solução para versões anteriores ao PHP5.6 é usar `call_user_func_array()` como mostram as respostas nos links.

[Como passo parâmetros dinamicos numa preparedStatment? e Select no MySQL com um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101087/91)

[Select no MySQL com um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30181/91)

**Abordagem com PHP5.6**

Com o PHP 5.6 e a ajuda do [...](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)(unpacking arguments) é possível passar um array para `bind_param()` de forma simples.

```
$valores = array('Doge', 'doge@wow.com', 'wow value');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO t (c1,c2,c3) VALUES(?,?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', ...$valores);
if(!$stmt->execute()){
     echo $stmt->error;
}
```