# Como passar um valor em array em bind_param no mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou fazendo assim, mas sempre da erro por causa do array, alguém sabe como resolver isso:

```
public function Verificar(string $tabela,string $parametros,array ...$usuario) {
            $this->Query = $this->Conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE $tabela");
            $this->Query->bind_param($parametros,$usuario);
            $this->Query->execute();
            $this->ResultadoUser = $this->Query->get_result();
            return $this->ResultadoUser;
        }
```

Comment: vc não pode passar diretamente um array para `bind_param()`.

Comment: existe alguma solução neste caso ?

Comment: Dependendo da versão do php tem uma opção mais simples [veja aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101977/91)

Answer (score 0):

Se a solução proposta no comentário pelo rray não ajudar, você pode considerar usar um framework. Recomendo, uso, o **[Pixie](https://github.com/usmanhalalit/pixie)**. Abaixo um exemplo do SELECT:

```
$query = QB::table('my_table')->where('nome', 'Jose');
$query->count();
```

Talvez não seja a resposta que você espera, mas é uma opção a considerar. Para fazer o que você quer de passar vários parâmetros ao mesmo tempo você pode passar no formato esperado pelo Pixie.

Veja a documentação com vários exemplos.