# Gravando apenas a ultima linha no BD

Tags: php, mysql, array

To fazendo um formulário para dar entrada em produtos no estoque (espelho da NF) para isso estou usando um cód em javascript para clonar as linhas.

Até ai tudo bem, o problema e na hora de mandar cadastrar pois ele só cadastra a ultima linha dos produtos, será problema no meu insert, no formulário ou no java?

To quebrando a cabeça para montar array/foreach  e não acho onde está o problema, me ajudem por favor....

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO lc_detalhe (cat_id,qtd,valor_unid,valor_total,controle_id) values 
      ('$cat_id','$qtd','$valor_unid','$valor_total',LAST_INSERT_ID())");
```

Parte do cód.

```
<td><input type="text" name="id" style="text-align:center" disabled="true" /></td>
    <td><select name="cat_id[]">
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['nome']?></option>
<?php }?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="qtd[]" class="qtd" required name="qtd"
      style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input name="valor_unid[]" type="text" required name="valor_unid"
      maxlength="30" 
      onblur="Calc(this)"
      class="valor_unid" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="valor_total[]"
      class="vtotal"   readonly="readonly"
      style="text-align:center"/>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="img/excluir.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="img/+.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </td></tr>
  <tr>
<p><input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" /></p>
```

---

acho que to chegando em algum lugar..kkkk

Agora ele ta gravando até demais no BD. quando ele tem apenas uma linha ele grava certinho mas quando tem mais de uma linha ele triplica as linhas no BD e não respeita o LAST_INSERT_ID()

Olha como montei o insert:

```
    foreach($_POST["cat_id"] as $cat_id)
    foreach($_POST["qtd"] as $qtd)
    foreach($_POST["valor_unid"] as $valor_unid)
    foreach($_POST["valor_total"] as $valor_total)

mysql_query("INSERT INTO lc_detalhe (cat_id,qtd,valor_unid,valor_total,controle_id) values
    ('$cat_id','$qtd','$valor_unid','$valor_total',LAST_INSERT_ID())");
```

olha como está os campos do formulário:

```
 <td><select name="cat_id[]">

<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['nome']?></option>
<?php }?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="qtd[]" class="qtd" required name="qtd"
      style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input name="valor_unid[]" type="text" required name="valor_unid"
      maxlength="30" 
      onblur="Calc(this)"
      class="valor_unid" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="valor_total[]"
      class="vtotal"   readonly="readonly"
      style="text-align:center"/>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="img/excluir.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="img/+.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </td></tr>
  <tr>
<p><input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" /></p>
```

Olha como ele gravou no BD: ele perdeu o controle_id a partir do 3º registro que vem do LAST_INSERT_ID(), os valores não batem com o que foi digitado e inseriu varias vezes o mesmo registro

```
 Textos completos   id  controle_id  cat_id qtd valor_unid       valor_total
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   1   1   533 1630     1.00               1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   2   1   533 1630     1.00   16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   3   2   533 1630     0.01   1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   4   3   533 1630            0.01    16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   5   4   533 1631    1.00    1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   6   5   533 1631    1.00    16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   7   6   533 1631    0.01    1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   8   7   533 1631    0.01    16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   9   8   534 1630    1.00    1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   10  9   534 1630    1.00    16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   11  10  534 1630    0.01    1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   12  11  534 1630    0.01    16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   13  12  534 1631    1.00    1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   14  13  534 1631    1.00    16.31
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   15  14  534 1631    0.01    1630.00
 Edita Edita    Copiar Copiar   Apagar Apagar   16  15  534 1631    0.01    16.31
```

Comment: mostra o array/foreach que você desenvolveu?

Comment: Atente-se ao fato que o `input name='qtd'` não possui os caracteres `[]` no respectivo nome e, desta forma, ficaria único ao fazer a requisição. Aliás, tanto o `input name='qtd'`quanto `input name='valor_unid'` possuem o atributo `name` duplicado.

Comment: Finalmente, não utilize mais as funções `mysql_*` do PHP, leia mais sobre isso [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql), [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63331/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-as-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-mysql-connect-e-mysqli-connect-em-php) e [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68232/usar-pdo-%C3%A9-a-maneira-mais-segura-de-se-conectar-a-um-bd-com-php).

Comment: lê esta resposta [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101965/mysqli-fazer-bind-com-um-array-de-valores?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo de insert com foreach

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $i = 0;
  foreach ($_POST as $val) {
     $qtd = $_POST['qtd'][$i];
     $valor_unid = $_POST['valor_unid'][$i];
     ........................
     ........................

     mysql_query("INSERT INTO lc_detalhe (cat_id,qtd,valor_unid,valor_total,controle_id) values 
  ('$cat_id','$qtd','$valor_unid','$valor_total',LAST_INSERT_ID())"); 

   $i++;
  } 
}
```