# foreach gravando varias vezes no BD

Tags: foreach

Pessoal to fazendo um formulário de entrada de produtos (espelho da NF) que tem a opção de clonar as linhas para incluir mais produtos.

Esse formulário grava em 2 tabelas 1º cabeçalho da NF e a 2º grava os detalhes onde tem o ID do produto a quantidade o valor unitário o valor total e o ID do cabeçalho para isso uso o LAST_INSERT_ID()

Só que estou com um problema montei o foreach conforme abaixo quando tenho apenas uma linha no formulário mas quando tem mais de um item ele fica doido, grava diversas vezes no banco com dados incorretos e a partir da segunda linha ele perde o LAST_INSERT_ID()

Onde estou errando?

```
    foreach($_POST["cat_id"] as $cat_id)
    foreach($_POST["qtd"] as $qtd)
    foreach($_POST["valor_unid"] as $valor_unid)
    foreach($_POST["valor_total"] as $valor_total)

mysql_query("INSERT INTO lc_detalhe (cat_id,qtd,valor_unid,valor_total,controle_id) values
    ('$cat_id','$qtd','$valor_unid','$valor_total',LAST_INSERT_ID())");


e o formulário

    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4">
    <tr>
      <td class="bd_titulo">ID</td><td class="bd_titulo">Produto</td><td class="bd_titulo">Quantidade</td><td class="bd_titulo">Valor Unitario</td><td class="bd_titulo">Valor Total</td></tr>
  <tr class="linhas">
    <td><input type="text" name="id" style="text-align:center" disabled="true" /></td>
    <td><select name="cat_id[]">
<?php
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['nome']?></option>
<?php }?></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="qtd[]" class="qtd" required name="qtd"
      style="text-align:center" />
    </td>
    <td> 
      <input name="valor_unid[]" type="text" required name="valor_unid"
      maxlength="30" 
      onblur="Calc(this)"
      class="valor_unid" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="valor_total[]"
      class="vtotal"   readonly="readonly"
      style="text-align:center"/>
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="img/excluir.jpg" border="0" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="4">
        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="img/+.jpg" border="0" /></a>
    </td></tr>
  <tr>
<p><input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" /></p>
```

Comment: Não crie perguntas repetidas aqui na comunidade, por favor. Você já postou este problema, então continue com a discussão lá. Ficar recriando de forma repetida só poluirá o site. Veja sua outra pergunta: [Gravando apenas a ultima linha no BD](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/197593/gravando-apenas-a-ultima-linha-no-bd)

Comment: é que aquele problema foi resolvido, agora estou com outro problema