# Problemas ao usar o INSERT no PHP (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

eu (iniciante na área de desenvolvimento php) estou tendo problemas ao inserir dados usando o codigo abaixo:

```
    <?php

$conn = new mysqli("zz", "zz", "zz", "zz"); 
// Alterei a string de conexão por questão de segurança

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  echo "Error: " .$conn->connect_error;
}

$login = 'user';
$senha = '12345';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_usuario (login,senha) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Ele executa normalmente, sem apresentar nenhum erro, porém quando verifico meu banco de dados, nenhum dado foi, de fato, incluido :/.
Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Segue print do banco: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem exemplos em: [Mysqli fazer bind com um array de valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101977/91) e [Como converter uma ligação de MySQL para MySQLi?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32822/91)

Answer (score 1):

Depois de criar o `Prepared Statement` precisa fazer o `bind` dos valores:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $senha);
```

Caso contrário não é nada executado:

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("zz", "zz", "zz", "zz"); 
    // Alterei a string de conexão por questão de segurança

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      echo "Error: " .$conn->connect_error;
    }

    $login = "user";
    $senha = "12345";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_usuario (login,senha) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $login, $senha);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Eu havia omitido uma parte do meu codigo sem querer (na verdade, deixei como comentario, e era justamente o bind param: $stmt->bind_param('ss', $login, $pass);  Justamente com tal comando que não me apresenta nenhum erro e mesmo assim não chega a incluir :/

Comment: Mas resolve o seu problema? Ou mantém-se?

Comment: Continua com o problema. Existe uma outra forma para inclusao de dados sem a utilização do bind param?

Comment: Experimente colocar os valores do `$login` e `$senha` entre aspas ao invés de plicas. Resposta editada com essa correção.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema :), ao tentar salvar com '?' via que armazenava normalmente, logo percebi que era problema na variável. Verifiquei novamente o codigo e vi que o problema na verdade era na passagem do nome da variavel no parametro do bind_param (eu passei como $pass sendo que a variável era $senha). Consertei e agora está armazenando normalmente :D. Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda! Abraços