# receber form com var_dump

Tags: php

Galera, atualmente eu envio um `form` com vários `POST`, recebo todos e os adiciono no BD. Porém estou vendo um método usando o `var_dump`, mas não sei como implantar ele no meu código.

Um exemplo de como eu faço hoje:

```
            <?php
        if ((!empty($action)) and ( $action == "envia")) {

            // Recebe dados
            $nome1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome1', FILTER_DEFAULT);
            $nome2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome2', FILTER_DEFAULT);

            // Adino no BD mysql
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO nomes VALUES ('0', '$nome1')");
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO nomes VALUES ('0', '$nome2')");
        }
        ?>

        <form name="form" method="post" action="index.php?action=envia">
            <input  type='text' name='nome1'>
            <input  type='text' name='nome2'>      
            <button type='submit'>Enviar</button>
        </form>
```

Tem alguma forma de eu simplificar isso com o `var_dump`. Esse é um exemplo simples, pois tenho um formulário com uns 30 `POST`.

Comment: o `var_dump()` não parece resolver o seu problema, está mais para um _array_!

Comment: Você utiliza um insert na mesma tabela para cada elemento do seu form?

Comment: @FleuquerLima isso e um exemplo, na verdade tenho um `form` onde eu posso cadastras até 10 usuário de uma vez, então queria mudar o método que eu faço entendeu.

Comment: var_dump() não foi feito pra receber nem enviar nada, e sim para printar um array / objeto na tela.

Comment: @rray como seria esse método com array?

Comment: Pode fazer [assim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/48736/91). Seu campo do form deve enviar um array, para isso basta adicionar colchetes no `name` faça um verificação, após faça um foreach com o insert ou monte a string do insert e mande de uma só vez para o banco.

Comment: @rray tem como voce responder a pergunta com uma exemplo? assim posso aceitar e finalizar a pergunta.

Comment: Mas ele já colocou um exemplo no post que te passou o link, da uma olhada lá

Comment: ok, eu não tinha visto hahahha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não testei porque meu `php` não está reconhecendo o `filter_input`, mas assim deve pegar:

```
<?php
// povoando post (para teste)
$_POST['nome1'] = "o";
$_POST['nome2'] = "v";
$_POST['nome3'] = "e";
$_POST['nome4'] = "r";
$_POST['nome5'] = "f";
$_POST['nome6'] = "l";
$_POST['nome7'] = "o";
$_POST['nome8'] = "w";

var_dump($_POST);

$valores = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    array_push($valores, filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_DEFAULT));

var_dump($valores);

foreach($valores as $value)
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO nomes VALUES ('0', '$value')");
```

Como citado nos comentários, o `var_dump` serve apenas para exibição, segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php#refsect1-function.var-dump-description):

> **var_dump** — Mostra informações sobre a variável
>
> Esta função mostrará uma representação estruturada sobre uma ou mais expressões, incluindo
>   o tipo e o valor. Arrays e objetos são explorados recursivamente com
>   valores identados na estrutura mostrada.

Ou seja, é usado apenas para testar o sistema, ver os valores das suas variáveis.

No código usei um `foreach` para percorrer os dados do $_POST, assim fazendo a filtração de dados e colocando o resultado da filtração em uma lista, após isso, tenho outro `foreach` que vai executar no `mysqli`. O mesmo poderia ser feito com:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO nomes VALUES ('0', '$value')");
}
```

Ou também:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO nomes VALUES ('0', '" . filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_DEFAULT) . "')");
```

Comment: Estiloso esse povoamento ai...